# global max of local mins of k contiguous elements

Tags: algorithm

If this question appears to be a replicate, please point it out.

The problem states:

> Given an array of n elements and an integer k <= n, find the max of {min{a_i+1 ... a_i+k} for i in {0 ... n-k}}, i.e. find the max of the mins of k contiguous numbers.
>
> For example, let the sequence a = {10, 21, 11, 13, 16, 15, 12, 9} and k = 3.
> The max is 13 for block {13, 16, 15}.

Hopefully the problem is clear!

It is straight forward to have a simple "brute force" making it O(nk). I am wondering if we can do it in O(nlogn) with "divide and conquer" or even in O(n) possibly with "dynamic programming".

It appears to me that if I try "divide and conquer", I have to deal with a set of blocks that is just across the middle border. Yet figuring out the max in that case seems to take O(k2), making the whole recurrence O(nk) again. (Maybe I get the numbers wrong somewhere!)

Looking for directions from you guys! Words and pseudocode are welcome!

Comment: It's always a good idea to include an example with explanation to supplement the problem statement.

Comment: @Dukeling Sorry I forgot, see updated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in O(n log k) time; I'll start you off with a tip.

Suppose you have elements a<sub>i+1</sub>, ..., a<sub>i+k</sub> in some data structure with logarithmic time insert and constant time min operations (like a min heap). Can you use that to get the same data structure, but with elements a<sub>i+2</sub>, ..., a<sub>i+k+1</sub>
 in O(log k) time?

Once you have that, then you can basically go through all of the consecutive groups of `k` and take the maximum of the minimums normally.

Comment: I am seeing your point! Quite neat! Just wondering if we can do it in a "divide and conquer" way?

Comment: One thing about trying "divide and conquer" though; you'd also have to deal with the possibility that the group of `k` you're looking for is sitting on the divide (and hence has bits in both halves)

Comment: Yep, applying this data structure way in that part can give O(nlogk) for "divide and conquer". Thanks! My brain just got stuck...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to solve it using a dynamic programming-like solution. We construct an array "ys" that stores the mins of ever increasing ranges. It uses the idea that if the `ys` currently store mins of ranges of length p, then if we do for all i: `ys[i] = min(ys[i], ys[i+p])`, then we've now got mins of ranges of length 2p. Similarly, if we do `ys[i] = min(ys[i], ys[i+p], xs[i+2p])` then we've got mins of ranges of length 2p+1. By using a technique very like exponentiation-by-squaring, we can end up with ys storing min-ranges of length k.

```
def mins(xs, k, ys):
    if k == 1: return ys
    mins(xs, k // 2, ys)
    for i in xrange(len(ys)):
        if i + k//2 < len(ys): ys[i] = min(ys[i], ys[i+k//2])
        if k % 2:
            if i+k-1 < len(ys): ys[i] = min(ys[i], xs[i+k-1])
    return ys

def maxmin(xs, k):
    return max(mins(xs, k, xs[:]))
```

We call `mins` recursively log_2(k) times, and otherwise we iterate over the ys array once per call. Thus, the algorithm is O(n log k).